# html5 database save '?!& etc as special characters in the html5 database

Tags: javascript, sql, database, string, html

i Have an HTML5 application where I am trying to save all special characters as special chars

for example

eihefrgredirngfdig'dfdfgdfgg... i  want the ' to be saved as a special char. is there a way to do a string replace?

```
case 5:
            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS notes(id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, now, created DATETIME, title, note)');
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO notes(now, created, title, note) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)', [now, mytime, notetitle, notenote]);
```

everything else is working. i just want to be able to replace any and all special chars with the html5 special char equivalent. does anyone have any suggestions on hosw I can string replace? I have done it in php but I cant seem to get it to work properly in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no function which you could simple use. However I don't know your `tx.executeSql()` function but it looks like a prepaird statment (just wired that you use the tag javascript) there you don't need to care about correct escaping the input strings the database framework should handle that itself.

```
function myReplace(instr) {
    instr.replace("'", "\\'").replace("?","\\?");
}
```

The code above masks the input chars `'` and `?`, it can be simple extended for you needs.